# Is the sentence structure in the sentence "Would you be so kind as to [verb] ...?" correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-choice

So, would a sentence like "would you be so kind as to help me out with this project" be correct?

Are there any similar request type sentences with the phrase "would you be so kind ..." with possibly different continuations?

(I'm always looking to improve on my English; so, I'd greatly appreciate it if you would point out any grammatical mistakes I've made in describing my question)

Answer (score 2):

> would you be so kind as to...? or would you be kind enough to...?

This a very polite and formal way of asking somebody to do something.

For example:

> "Would you be so kind as to help me cross the road?"
>   "Of course. May I take your hand?"
>
> "Would you be kind enough to bring me a pot of tea, please?"
>   "Certainly, madam."

[Source](https://www.englishclub.com/ref/esl/Conversational_Phrases/W/would_you_be_so_kind_as_to..._would_you_be_kind_enough_to...__4564.php)

Comment: what's the difference between "... as to ..." vs "... to ..."?

Comment: There isn't a lot of difference and both are acceptable. I would say "as to" feels a lot more formal. Please do note that they require slightly different set ups, "would you be kind enough as to" doesn't really work and feels much more unnatural

Comment: oh I see, thank you!